# Convert RDD values in KVP to integers in PySpark

Tags: python, type-conversion, integer, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to convert the column[2] values in my RDD key-value pairs from strings to integers so that I am able to sum them up and calculate an average.

I attempted to have column [2] automatically display as integers during the mapping phase but I am getting the error, " TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute ' getitem ' "

```
textfile = sc.textFile("hdfs://...csv")
test = textfile.map(lambda x: (x.split(",")[1], x.split(",")(int[2]))
```

What is the correct way to convert/map the column[2] value as an integer in the PySpark RDD?

Comment: Your error is because of the `int[2]` - you're trying to get the 3rd item from a datatype, which doesn't make sense (This is what the error message says). I think you meant to write: `test = textfile.map(lambda x: (x.split(",")[1], int(x.split(",")[2]))`, i.e. convert the 2nd element in `x.split(",")` to an `int`. Also keep in mind that python is 0-indexed, so your code as written assumes that `len(x.split(",")) >= 3`

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest trying this

```
import numpy as np
mat = sc.parallelize([np.array(['', '10.0', '100.0']), np.array(['2.0', '', '200.0']), np.array(['50.0', '30.0', ''])])
colnumber = 2
rdd_col = mat.map(lambda x: x[colnumber])
rdd_col_without_na = rdd_col.filter(lambda x: x!='')
rdd_float = rdd_col_without_na.map(lambda x:[x]).map(lambda x: float(x[0]))
```

You can then calculate the mean using the mean() function

```
meanOfRddCol = rdd_float.mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comment, the issue is the indexing. However I wanted to add that you should also check for null values and that you could use tuples right away, which is easier to understand and use.

I would suggest doing the following:

```
test = textfile.map(lambda x: x.split(','))
remove_nulls = test.filter(lambda (x,y): y is not None)
with_ints = remove_nulls.map(lambda (x,y): (x,int(y)))
```

Now you can compute easily an average

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this:

```
test = textfile.map(lambda x: (x.split(",")[1], int(x.split(",")[2])))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).